# Meteor Subscribe & Publish with external api

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to connect my Meteor Subscribe and Publish to my api, the Publish is calling the API and returning the data no problem but I cant seem to load my data on the template.

Below is my code.

**boards.js**

```
import './boards.html';

Tracker.autorun(function() {
  Meteor.subscribe('getUserBoards');
});
```

**boards.html**

```
<template name="userBoards">
  {{#each boards}}
    {{this.id}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

**index.js**

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('getUserBoards', function getBoards() {
    var self = this;
    try {
      var response = HTTP.get(Meteor.settings.private.api.url+'users/'+this.userId+'/boards/');

      _.each(response.data.boards, function(item) {
        var doc = {
          id: item._id,
          name: item.name,
          urlFriendlyName: item.urlFriendlyName,
          access: item.access,
          backgroundImage: item.backgroundImage,
          products: item.products,
          sharedCount: item.meta.shared,
          totalProducts: item.meta.totalProducts,
          dateAdded: item.meta.dateAdded
        };

        self.added('boards', item._id, doc);
      });

      self.ready();

    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Where is your template helper for returning `boards` to the `userBoards` template?

Comment: @MichelFloyd that's what I must be missing, how do I go about doing this? Sorry I'm new to Meteor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your html template:

```
<template name="userBoards">
  {{#each boards}}
    {{this.id}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

You need a helper to return a *cursor* called `boards`:

js:

```
Template.userBoards.helpers({
  boards(){
    return Boards.find();
  }
});
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot was driving me nuts. I also needed to add Boards = new Mongo.Collection('boards');