# Publish/subscribe not loading in Blaze template

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

My code was working fine until I implemented publish/subscribe. I followed [the basic tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe) and checked [the source code](https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos) and I'm not doing anything different. Everything builds and runs but nothing from MongoDB gets displayed in the Blaze template.

imports/api/features.js

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
   Meteor.publish('features', function featuresPublication() {
      return Features.find({});
   });
   Meteor.publish('comments', function commentsPublication() {
      return Features.find({}, {fields: {comments: 0}});
   })
};
```

client/main.js

```
Template.body.onCreated(function bodyOnCreated() {
  Meteor.subscribe('features'); 
});
```

client/main.html

```
<body>
  <h1 id="title">Feature Requests</h1>
  {{#if currentUser}}
    <button class="ui green button create" id="create">Add a New     Feature Request</button>
    {{> requestForm}}
    {{#each features}}
      {{> feature}}
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    {{> loginButtons}}
  {{/if}}
</body>
```

**Edit #1**

Before I ran `meteor remove autopublish` my code looked like this and worked:

```
Template.body.helpers({ 
  features() {
    return Features.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
  },
  comments() {
    return Features.find({}, {fields: {comments: 0}}); 
  },
});
```

**Edit #2**

Thanks to everyone who contributed an answer. I fundamentally misunderstood how publish/subscribe worked. I didn't realize I still needed to call `return Features.find({})` after I subscribed. Here's my working code:

```
import { Features } from '../imports/api/features.js';

import '../imports/api/features.js'

Template.body.onCreated(function bodyOnCreated() {
  Meteor.subscribe('features'); 
});

Template.body.helpers({
  features: function() {
    return Features.find({});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregard the first answer. The lack of an `autorun` is what first caught my attention but since you're not passing any args to `subscribe` it is not needed.

My next question would be: In `client/main.html`, where is the reference to `features` coming from? Is there a `features` helper on `Template.body`? If not, you'll need to add it:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  features: function() {
    return Features.find({});
  }
});
```

Also, see [Meteor Subscribe & Publish with external api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027694)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not seem to do anything. I also tried several variations on this including using `Meteor.subscribe` instead of `Features.find({})`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Template.body.onCreated(function() {
  const self = this;
  self.autorun(() => {
    self.subscribe('features');
  });
});
```

Also, see https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#organizing-subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks for answering unfortunately this did not work. I also tried using `this.autorun`, `this.subscribe`, `Meteor.autorun`, and `Meteor.subscribe`.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using the imports directory. Have you remembered to import your publication file to the server/main.js file?

server/main:

```
import 'imports/path/to/publications.js'
```

Comment: Yes, `import { Features } from '../imports/api/features.js';`

Comment: Nope, that is you importing your collection. You need to import the file that the publocation is saved in on to the server. You can do that using the line in my answer. If you don't do that the publication isn't registered on the server and meteor won't be able to run it. I suspect that is your issue